# Can I hint text line-break point in Android buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout

Perhaps this is too much to expect, but can I set a hint where to break lines in case a button's text is displayed in multiple lines?

It seems that for Japanese & Korean text, the button text breaks within a single word. For example, in this example below, it was broken like "感じてね、見つめる\n瞳", but if I manually broke it, I would have chosen "感じてね、\n見つめる瞳" instead. For "어제 온 고깃배가 고향으로", I would have chosen "어제 온 고깃배가\n고향으로", since "고향으로" is kind of one word without a space.

I do not want to hard-code "\n", because if there is room, the text can be displayed in one line. I thought if there is a way to Android to break at here, if you must break the line. Something like,

```
    <Button
        android:text="感じてね、見つめる瞳"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:breakHint="5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Is there something like that in the framework?

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:text="感じてね、見つめる瞳"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:text="感じてね、見つめる瞳"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:text="어제 온 고깃배가 고향으로"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:text="어제 온 고깃배가 고향으로"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```